# avro-maven-plugin generates unused imports

Tags: java, maven, warnings, maven-plugin, avro

I'm using Apache Kafka with AVRO.
We are creating the Java classes by writing AVDL files and using avro-maven-plugin with compiler, etc. to generating/compiling them.

After generation all Java classes generated from AVDL files with record types containing unused imports like:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
```

Utf8 import is really sometimes used, but often is generated and not used.
GenericArray I never found anywhere used.

Is there a possibility to prevent generating these imports if they are not used? It's not so nice to generate code with already containing warnings.

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
          only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>1.11.3</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore/>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>target</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>avdl-generation</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/avdl/</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.avdl</include>
              </includes>
              <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <doclint>none</doclint>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

I tried to find some information regarding this in the internet but didn't found anything.
Would be good to get generated Java code without warnings.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it. It's generated code, it doesn't need to be perfect. And you shouldn't enable linters and warning checks on generated code in the first place.